# Making a "file gateway" in php or apache

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I'm not sure I'm using the right terms, so sorry from the start and please be patient

What I'm trying to implement is a kind of protection for my files from a folder X in my "www" folder, I was able to create my "php checker" which will check if I have the permissions to view and if the file exists I redirect to that file ( I'm using symfony2 ). I was trying to read the file content and give it back - but it makes CPU go crazy so that's a bad solution.
Note: I'm not sure the "file gateway" is right, I was doing some research and people told me to create one, after some more research and the absence of those people I decided that "what I'm doing" should be it

Besides that I was able to limit direct access to files, now I want to open it just to redirects and only from the same "server", or some other ideas if you have.

Not sure this is the best solution, if anyone can suggest something better - pretty please tell me.Most of my research fails as I anything I google will result in responses on how to remove the 403 or bringing it back - nothing more complex.

For now my apache config

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted

        DirectoryIndex app_dev.php app.php index.php index.html
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
         RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should hide all of the restricted files behind your /www/ (public) folders/files.

In the restricted public folder, place a php file that will handle the file request. It can check from a list of IP addresses and if approved, get the file, stream it with base64, copy it to a public folder with a special file name, ect.

If the restricted files are php files, then you can simply "include" them if access is granted.